# Linked scr to new project build in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I am using Eclipse 3.8.1. I have one project with sources and one which I build.

```
--ProjectSRC (from svn)
    -- src
       --main.java

--Project_build (builded project using ProjectSRC files)
    --src
      --main.java
    --build
        main.class
```

I have svn project and I downloaded locally these files but I want to make a new project from them. I am trying to link sources but when I change something in eclipse for example in file main.java in **Project_build** , another project in eclipse which is linked with the svn do not see changes of this file, so I have to copy changes manually, or to build the project with sources. And if I do that, when I *synchronize with the repository* there are a lot of build directories and .project files which every time I have to unchecked.

So how to connect sources from one svn project and to create new with them and when a change become to be reflected on the two places, through Eclipse?

Comment: Are you committing the changes to your SVN repository? Is the other project pointing to the same repository (and are you updating the second project after the commit on the first?)

Comment: No the changes are not committed I want to try locally if all test runs and then to commit. 
The second project points to the source, not to repo.
It is not necessary to update the second project because the changes are local.